# Google Analytics Query Explorer 2

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is the Google Analytics Query Explorer 2 API real time?  I need to pull data from my google analytic profile as close to real time as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the real time Analytics data with the Google APIs Explorer here: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/analytics.data.realtime.get

Answer (score 0):

The Query Explorer is pulling from the Core Reporting API. That is not real-time data. It can be several hours behind.

> > This tool lets you play with the Core Reporting API by building queries to get data from your Google Analytics views (profiles). You can use these queries in any of the client libraries to build your own tools.

Answer (score 0):

The query explorer pulls data through the Core Reporting API, just as jks answer says. However, you could utilize the new function of the [Real Time API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/), which is currently in beta, to access this kind of data.